# bits and bytes in java

Tags: java, byte, bit-shift

Can we have in Java one byte whose upper 4 bits represent values like 0x40/0x80 and lower 4 bits representing values like 0,1,2,3.If yes then how do we retrieve values out of that on byte?Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try googling [`java bit manipulation`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+bit+manipulation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example is probably easier than using words to describe it.

```
byte data = 0x74;
int high4 = (data >> 4) & 0xf;
int low4 = data & 0xf;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create wrapper class for `byte` or `int` with methods that fidget bits.

```
int first4bits = (byteContainer >> 4) & 0xF;
int last4bits = byteContainer & 0xF;
```

The problem is that such actions are inappropriate in Java.